# How to skip first element in webpage and choose second element using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have two elements in webpage with same linktext in same table structure. I have to ignore first element and select second element everytime if present.
But problem is selenium selecting first element every time, How can I select second element instead of first element(ignore first element)?

***I can't use anything other than Linktext to identify that element using selenium, That's the constraint.***

Comment: is the values present in the table? if yes, then choose the particular cell locator value

Comment: Use driver.findElements(By......) which returns a list... if list size is 2, then take the second element. Else ignore based on size.

Comment: How to check list size and how to select second element of that list. Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: @Parth list.size() second element - list(1)... Just google for a java list tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when elements having same link text or having same loactors, there is one collection present in java i.e  List
create a list of webelements having such kind of scenario, then by there index you can access the elements.

```
List<WebElement> list1 = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Services"));
for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++)
{
 System.out.println(i+" "+list1.getText());
 //this can be used incase number of elements is more and no time to count there index
}
list1.get(1).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is for getting second element via link text where I used collection class to store all same kind of elements.

```
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Services"));;
li.get(1).click();
```